# Taking initiation from a guru

Tags: sri-vaishnava, initiation

Namaskaram

I am not from a Brahmin varna and a married female from a Hindu family. I’m currently involved in Krishna consciousness and bhakti and service to Bhagavan. I hear a lot of upanasam from Sri Sampradaya of Sri Ramanujacharya and would like to know if I can become his guru parampara disciple and get a guru to guide me to saranagati and service to Bhagavan. I don’t know the procedures and details but I am interested to  further my spiritual knowledge in Krishna bhakti. Please guide me.

Comment: personal advice not allowed on this forum.